# Copying files into working directory using system

Tags: r, copy, system

I am trying to copy a .txt file from one subfolder (Scripts) into a another sub folder (1). the folders are shown below using the list.files() function.

```
list.files()
[1] "1"       "Scripts"
```

Within the folder "Scripts" there is a text file named "population.isam"

```
list.files("Scripts")
[1] "population.isam"
```

I want to move it within R, using the,

```
system()
```

I use the following command within R

```
system("copy Scripts\\population.isam 1")
```

but I get the following warning

```
Warning message:
running command 'copy Scripts\population.isam  1' had status 127
```

But when I copy that command "copy Scripts\population.isam 1" into my cmd prompt it copys the file with no problem. Can anyone please help me out

Comment: Is this Windows? I suspect you need more complete paths; try pasting them together with `normalizePath`, so something like: `system(paste('copy', normalizePath('.\Scripts\population.isam'), normalizePath('.\1')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to just use `shell`, otherwise you need to call cmd.exe in your system command.

```
shell("copy Scripts\\population.isam 1")
```